# Flex DropDownList data to xml

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I`m a newbie on Flex and busy with a custom form to save form data to xml. I have created the form:

Form:

```
<s:Panel width="875" height="677" horizontalCenter="0" title="Add New Client to Database"
             verticalCenter="0">
        <s:Label x="17" y="23" text="Title:"/>
        <s:DropDownList  x="17" y="43" requireSelection="true">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList id="clientTitle" source="[Mr, Mnr, Dr]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
        <s:Label x="209" y="23" text="Gender:"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="clientGender" x="209" y="43" requireSelection="true">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[Male, Female]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
        <s:Label x="17" y="84" text="Full Names:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientNames" x="18" y="104" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="18" y="142" text="Surname:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientSurname" x="18" y="162" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="18" y="202" text="Age:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientAge" x="18" y="221" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="18" y="261" text="Address:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientAddress" x="17" y="281" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="17" y="322" text="City:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientCity" x="17" y="342" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="17" y="382" text="Country:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientCountry" x="17" y="402" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="18" y="443" text="Tel:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientTel" x="17" y="463" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="17" y="503" text="Fax:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientFax" x="17" y="522" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="17" y="560" text="Mobile:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientMobile" x="17" y="580" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="492" y="23" text="Email:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="clientEmail" x="492" y="43" width="350"/>
        <s:Label x="492" y="84" text="Extras:"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientCode8" x="527" y="104" label="License Code 8"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientCode10" x="527" y="130" label="License Code 10"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientCode14" x="527" y="156" label="License Code 14"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientSingle" x="684" y="104" label="Single"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientMarried" x="684" y="130" label="Maried"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientDevorced" x="684" y="156" label="Devorced"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="clientEducation" x="492" y="222" width="350" requireSelection="true">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[Not Finished School, Matric, Diploma, N3, N4, N5, N6, Degree]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>

        <s:Label x="492" y="202" text="Education Level:"/>

        <s:DropDownList id="clientIndustry" x="492" y="282" width="350" requireSelection="true">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[Not Finished School, Matric, Diploma, N3, N4, N5, N6, Degree]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>

        <s:Label x="492" y="261" text="Industry:"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="clientQualification" x="492" y="342" width="350" requireSelection="true">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[Not Qualified, Fitter, Boilmaker]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
        <s:Label x="492" y="322" text="Qualification:"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="clientSalary" x="492" y="402" width="350" requireSelection="true">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[0 - 1000, 1000 - 2000, 2000 - 3000, 3000 - 4000, 4000 - 5000, 5000 - 6000, 7000 - 8000, 8000 - 9000, 9000 - 10 000]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
        <s:Label x="492" y="382" text="Salary:"/>
        <s:Label x="492" y="443" text="Current Employed:"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientEmployed" x="527" y="467" label="Is Employed"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="clientNotEmployed" x="684" y="467" label="Not Employed"/>
        <s:Button x="585" y="523" label="Upload CV to Database"/>
        <s:Button x="607" y="580" label="Save New Client" buttonMode="true" click="saveRecruit(event)" useHandCursor="true"/>
    </s:Panel>
```

and here is my script to save to xml:

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
        protected function saveRecruit(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
            file = file.resolvePath("recruit.xml");
            var myXML:XML =<recruit>
                            <title>{clientTitle.toString()}</title>
                            <gender>{clientGender.toString()}</gender>
                            <names>{clientNames.text}</names>
                            <surname>{clientSurname.text }</surname>
                            <age>{clientAge.text}</age>
                            <address>{clientAddress.text}</address>
                            <city>{clientCity.text}</city>
                            <country>{clientCountry.text}</country>
                            <tel>{clientTel.text}</tel>
                            <fax>{clientFax.text }</fax>
                            <mobile>{clientMobile.text}</mobile>
                            <email>{clientEmail.text}</email>
                            <extras>{clientCode8.toString()}</extras>
                            <education>{clientEducation.toString()}</education>
                            <industry>{clientIndustry.toString()}</industry>
                            <qualification>{clientQualification.toString()}</qualification>
                            <salary>{clientSalary.toString()}</salary>
                            <employed>{clientEmployed.toString()}</employed>
                          </recruit>;
            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);
            fs.writeUTFBytes(myXML);
            fs.close();
            Alert.show("Thank You! You have now been entered.","Thank You!");
        }
```

I am unable to save the data to XML, any ideas?

Please help!

Comment: What error do you run into or what error condition? that is what happens versus what do you expect to happen, have you tried running in debug mode, put breakpoints in your saveRecruit method and step through it, if you're unsure how to do this just google "Flex debugging" you should be able to come up with something from Adobe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to use the `selectedItem` property:

```
var myXML:XML = 
    <recruit>
        <title>clientTitleInput.selectedItem</title>
        <gender>clientGenderInput.selectedItem</gender>
        ...
    </recruit>;
```

Note that `clientTitleInput` and `clientGenderInput` are the IDs of the DropDownLists, not of their dataProviders.